# Form not submitting with recaptcha validated using Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I want to submit my form when recaptcha is validated and not submit the form when it is not validated. My form is not submitting when ajax return a string "true". How do i do this?

```
  $("#submitbtn").click(function(e){
    challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
    responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ballot/validatecaptcha",
        data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "true"){
                $("#form2").submit();

            }else{
                $("#recaptcha_error").text("Error");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: make sure that 'data' has 'true' in it may be 'data' is a object..just check what you are returning

Comment: Hi.i can get into the if else statement that check if data is true, but the form is not submitting. I  suspect it might be the return false at the end of Ajax function.

Comment: just remove  return false; from the end and use e.preventDefault() in else statement.

Comment: Hi when I removed the return false and uses preventdefault on the else statement , the form get submitted. I do not want the form to be submitted with captcha fails

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved it. The solution is that i need to set async to false.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ballot/validatecaptcha",
    async: false,
    data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
    success: function(data){
        if(data == "true"){
            $("#form2").submit();

        }else{
            $("#recaptcha_error").text("Error");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Setting `async: false` is deprecated. https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#synchronous-flag